# How to update a price from a select and a checkbox with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the select box doing it's job but the checkbox leads to incorrect prices. I assume i need someway of seperating the values, doing the maths and returning the result to the output?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var firstPrice = 70;
      $("#price").text("£" + firstPrice + ".00");

      $(function() {
        $("select[name='vehicle']").change(function() {
          updateTotal();
        });
        updateTotal();

      });

      function updateTotal() {
        var newPrice = firstPrice;
        $("select[name='vehicle'] option:selected").each(function() {
          var carPrice = ($(this).data('value'));
          newPrice += parseFloat(carPrice);
        });
        $("#price").text("£" + newPrice + ".00");
        $("#total_amount").val(newPrice + ".00");

      };

      $("#return").click(function() {
        var isChecked = $('#return').is(':checked');
        if (isChecked == true) {
          var returnPrice = (newPrice * 2);
        } else {
          returnPrice = newPrice;
        }

        $("#price").text("£" + returnPrice + ".00");
        $("#total_amount").val(returnPrice);


      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="hidden" id="total_amount" name="total_amount" />
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Price:</td>
      <td>
        <div id="price"></div>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vehicle:</td>
      <td>
        <select id="vehicle" name="vehicle">
          <option data-value="0">4 Door Saloon</option>
          <option data-value="5">4 Door Estate</option>
          <option data-value="50">4 Door Executive</option>
          <option data-value="20">6 Seater</option>
          <option data-value="30">8 Seater</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Return</td>
      <td>
        <input name="return" id="return" type="checkbox" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Any help greatly appreciatd

Comment: your code snippet does nothing for me.

Comment: Hi @Draupadi, what do you mean by incorrect values? Are you saying that it is not multiplying the price by 2 when it is checked?

Comment: I do not understand how you count return price? if checked returnPrice = current Price * 2?